# Getting error in R when trying to calculate mean

Tags: r, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean of one of the variables in a data frame in R, and even though I have confirmed that the values are numeric I get the following error:

Warning in mean.default(x) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I have tried to calculate this in many different ways based on my research of different functions available, but I always end up with the same error.  Here's my latest attempt:

```
x <- all_trips_cleaned %>% 
  select(ride_length)

mean_ride_length <- mean(x)
```

I am new to R so this is probably a simple fi- any advice is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `select`, use `pull` to return a vector.  `select` returns a data.frame/tibble with a single column and the `mean` works on a vector.  From the 'x' dataset using OP's code, extract the 'ride_length' column with `$` or `[[` and get the `mean`

```
mean_ride_length <- mean(x$ride_length)
```

---

or use `pull`

```
library(dplyr)
x <- all_trips_cleaned %>% 
  pull(ride_length)

mean_ride_length <- mean(x)
```

Comment: pull worked beautifully- thank you so much!